# C3 chart x-axis tick count increases focus offset

Tags: charts, c3.js

I have a chart on which I have set the x-axis tick count to 5 but I noticed that when I do this that the vertical focus line is offset'ted from the mouse to the right.

```
axis: {
    x: {
        tick: {
            count: 5,
            format: d3.format('.2f')
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdywy21n/2/

How can I have the vertical focus line, line up with the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **[x axis type](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-type)**.

`'categories'` or `'indexed'` values should do the trick for you.

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'categories',
        tick: {
            count: 5,
            format: d3.format('.2f')
        }
    }
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5q1hz7n0/3/).